# I wish <C-h> deletes characters that were inserted before pressing the ESC button

Tags: cut-copy-paste

In the insert mode after pressing some characters the `<C-h>` combination pressed once removes the character to the left of the cursor.
When repeated it removes next left character and so on.

But it has its limitations. Let's see it on the following example:

I type `firstword` then press `esc` then type `secondword` and press `<C-h>` as many times as possible. It will only remove the  `secondword` and the `firstword` stays untouched.

I wish I had the `firstword` removed too. Is this possible?
The same counts for the `<C-w>` combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<C-h>` is backspace. Check `:h 'backspace'`

```
'backspace' 'bs'    string  (default "", set to "indent,eol,start"
                                in |defaults.vim|)
            global
    Influences the working of <BS>, <Del>, CTRL-W and CTRL-U in Insert
    mode.  This is a list of items, separated by commas.  Each item allows
    a way to backspace over something:
    value   effect  ~
    indent  allow backspacing over autoindent
    eol allow backspacing over line breaks (join lines)
    start   allow backspacing over the start of insert; CTRL-W and CTRL-U
        stop once at the start of insert.
    nostop  like start, except CTRL-W and CTRL-U do not stop at the start of
        insert.
```

Add to your vimrc `set backspace=indent,eol,start`

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem.